# How to extract the occurrence of a specific word in a new column in form of true/ false

Tags: sql

In column in certain rows a word is mentioned; on the basis of which I need to create a new column in the form of true/false depending on the mention of that word

```
select *
from table
case
  when column1 like '%word%' then 'True'
  else 'FALSE'
end as column_name
```

I just get an error

Comment: Move your case expression to the select clause, like `select table.*, case ... from...`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `case ... when`  in your select ,before `from` as follow:

```
SELECT *,CASE WHEN column1 LIKE '%word%' THEN 'True' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS AliasName FROM table
```